# How to update the single value which is not placed in listview adapter using android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-adapterview

MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.arunmannuru.arun.PromotionsFeedActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Location"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

FeedActivity.java

```
public class PromotionsFeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_promotions_feed);


        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String restoredText = prefs.getString("location", null);
        if (restoredText != null) {
            String location = prefs.getString("location", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
        }
        Location = new ArrayList<String>();
        Location.add(restoredText);

        Log.d(TAG,"Location"+Location);

        pfAdapter = new PromotionFeedAdapter(PromotionsFeedActivity.this,R.layout.livefeed_adapter,Titles);
        showData(pfAdapter);
    }

    public void showData(ArrayAdapter<String> adapter){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        show.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

FeedAdapter.java

```
public class PromotionFeedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public PromotionFeedAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        layout=resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent){

        //ViewHolder2 mainViewHolder = null;

        mContext = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView= inflater.inflate(layout,parent,false);


        // Layout Folder For Promotion

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.location = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtLocation);
        viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pf_title);
        viewHolder.category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pf_category);
        viewHolder.picture = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pf_main_pic);
        viewHolder.brand = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pf_type);

        // Navigation listner onClick Promotion

        viewHolder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getContext().startActivity(new Intent(getContext(),Webview.class));
            }
        });

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        TextView title = ((ViewHolder)convertView.getTag()).title;
        TextView category = ((ViewHolder) convertView.getTag()).category;
        TextView brand  = ((ViewHolder) convertView.getTag()).brand;
        TextView location = ((ViewHolder) convertView.getTag()).location;
        title.setText(getItem(position));
        category.setText(getItem(position));
        brand.setText(getItem(position));
        location.setText(getItem(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView brand;
        ImageView picture;
        TextView category;
        ImageView businessLogo;
        TextView location;
    }
}
```

I want to place the location value in the location field, which is dynamic value.The value it is going to return is single value.I want that to be populated on that field.It was not placed in list view. It is separate field which will display the location information.

Comment: and what doesn't work?

Comment: I want that location to be displayed.But it was showing that variable returning null reference.@Adithya

Comment: `location.setText(getItem(position));`  in this line?

Comment: check if String is actually stored,change `String restoredText = prefs.getString("location", null);` to `String restoredText = prefs.getString("location", "Loaction not saved");` see if it works then.

Comment: It was saved. I can be able to print the value on log. There is only one value returned from that reference I just want to display value on that field @Adithya

Comment: you can set text after you retrieved it from prefs ,`((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtLocation).setText(restoredText );`

Comment: When I'm try to set value like that it was showing expected textview widget but found void. @Adithya